# excel vba corrupts file - locked for editing + Removed Records: Sorting from /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, editing, locked

I have a file that has a vba macro to paste and sort data. 
Now everytime i save the file, when opening it says it has a problem = removed records :sorting from sheet3 ( even tough i do not have a sheet3 in my file) , and my file gets corrupted and 'locked for editing' .

Thank you in advance for any help.

' sum Macro

Range("A3").Select

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Pivot!R[3]C"
Range("A3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:A1500"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A3:A1500").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:ab1500"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A3:ab1500").Select
Range("AC3").Select
 Range("AC3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]+RC[-10]+RC[-8]+RC[-6]+RC[-4]+RC[-2]+RC[-14]+RC[-16]+RC[-20]+RC[-18]+RC[-22]+RC[-24]"
Range("AC3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AC3:AC1500")
Range("AC3:aC1500").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=60
Range("ac3").Select
Range("A3:ac1500").Select
Selection.copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("ac2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("ac2").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary table").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "ac2:ac1500"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary table").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:ac1500")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
   Range("A3").Select
```

'

End Sub

Comment: A good start would be to go through it yourself and remove all unnecessary code lines like duplicates, .SmallScroll, etc. You might also wish to decide if your sort data has a header or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try "File"-> "Options"->"Advanced"-> scroll down to see title,"When calculating this workbook"->check the box "update links to other documents" -> "Ok" and then try executing your code.

Answer (score 0):

> <sup>Recommended reading: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)</sup>
> <sub>It is better to get away from Select and Activate sooner than later.</sub>

Here is what is actually necessary for your code to execute everything from the original above.

```
Option Explicit

Sub summmit()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary table")
        .Activate
        .Range("A3:AB1500").FormulaR1C1 = "=Pivot!R[3]C"
        .Range("AC3:AC1500").FormulaR1C1 = _
          "=RC[-24]+RC[-22]+RC[-20]+RC[-18]+RC[-16]+RC[-14]+RC[-12]+RC[-10]+RC[-8]+RC[-6]+RC[-4]+RC[-2]"
        .Range("A3:ac1500") = .Range("A3:ac1500").Value
        With .Range("A2:ac1500")
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(29), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With
        .Range("A3").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

There does not appear to be any 'workbook-breaking' operations. Two things do come to mind: a) refresh the pivot table on the Pivot worksheet and b) start writing your formulas in xlA1 rather than the recorded xlR1C1 reference style. Additionally, the solution recommended by [arun v](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8627190/arun-v) shows merit.